# Get the enum class from a PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

I have a generic method that uses reflection to obtain PropertyInfo of a given type.

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(TItem).GetProperties();
```

In the case when one of the properties happens to be an Enum (easily checked by `property.PropertyType.IsEnum`), how can I get the actual Enum class just from the PropertyInfo class?

I need to use it later in a custom enum extension method that requires the type argument of the enum to be specified. E.g. if the enum class is this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}
```

My extension method has the following signature:

```
public static TEnum? GetEnumFromDescription<TEnum>(this string description) where TEnum : Enum
```

So I need something that would let me do this :

```
someString.GetEnumFromDescription<MyEnum>()
```

`property.PropertyType` returns an object of type `Type` which does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by *"get the actual Enum class"*? You have the type of the enum in `property.PropertyType`.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear, apologies

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question exactly, but this is generally what I use and it works for enums.

```
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties
            (
              System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
            | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
            | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
            );

    if (properties.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                AppendToOutputCache
                    (
                        $"[{properties[i].Name}] : " +
                        $"{properties[i].PropertyType} : " +
                        $"{properties[i].GetValue(obj, default)}",
                        m_OutputCache
                    );
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                AppendToOutputCache($"Exception:\n" + e.Message, m_OutputCache);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `AppendToOutputCache`? How is it related to the question asked?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I would dare guess, based on its name, it adds the properties the guy needs to some sort of cache.. lol, you people. Sorry next time I'll write foo() and bar() and something that isn't perfect naming convention. Jesus.

Comment: 1) I have not downvoted your answer 2) Based on the update it is not what OP needs 3) There is no mention of `AppendToOutputCache` in the question 4) My question has nothing to do with the actual name used and changing it `foo`/`bar` will not change a thing.